# python pygame - player and enemy and bullet colliding

Tags: pygame

Im working on a "shooting" game with Character class and 5 different bullet class's.
The player and the enemies are object of the Character class.
I set the bullet start position in the center of the character rect(so bullets came out of character).

The collision is defined by colliderect.
Example:  "enemy.rect.colliderect(bullet1)"
Its work fine when the player shoot the enemy.
the problem start if the enemy start to shoot on the player due to his bullets are colliding in his own rect.

I can solve that by multiple the 'bullet' class. And then player and enemy will shoot from different class's. But each character got 5 different bullet class and each class got different variables and and the shorter class its a lot of code.

i'm pretty sure theres a smart solution instead muliple my code line (~500 lines)

any suggestion? thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is that you could simply provide an additional argument to the bullets: a rectangle that shouldn't be checked. So when checking for
bullet collisions you exclude this rectangle from checking.

Minimal example (explanation in code comments):

```py
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Bullet:
    # provide an argument for what to check and what to exclude
    def __init__(self, start_pos, x_direction, check, exclude):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=start_pos)
        self.x_direction = x_direction
        self.check, self.exclude = check, exclude
        self.x_velocity = 5 * self.x_direction
        self.damage = 5
        self.destroy = False

    def draw(self, surf):
        surf.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        # go over the list of entities to check
        for entity in self.check:
            # if the entity is not the one that is excluded and the entity has
            # attributes that are needed here check for collision
            # and if there is then set the destroy flag to True
            # and stop updating. Also some check to see if the bullet has traveled
            # too far or somethin like that could be added
            if (entity is not self.exclude and hasattr(entity, 'health')
                    and hasattr(entity, 'rect')):
                if self.rect.colliderect(entity.rect):
                    entity.health -= self.damage
                    self.destroy = True
                    return
        self.rect.move_ip(self.x_velocity, 0)


# simple entity class to represent entities (in this case
# only the players and enemies since theoretically this could
# be base class both for bullets and players and enemies)
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, name):
        self.color, self.name = color, name
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 30, 60)
        self.health = 100
        self.prev_health = self.health

    def draw(self, surf):
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, self.color, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        # if health has been reduced print the current health
        if self.health < self.prev_health:
            print(f'{self.name} health: {self.health}')
            self.prev_health = self.health


# create the entities
player = Entity(100, 200, (0, 255, 0), 'player')
enemy = Entity(370, 200, (255, 0, 0), 'enemy')
# create a list to store bullets in
bullets = []

while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    
    # create a list for bullets to remove
    # so that they can be removed later
    # without interfering with the checking for loop
    remove_bullets = []
    for bullet in bullets:
        # if the bullet should be destroyed don't update it
        # and add to the bullets to remove
        if bullet.destroy:
            remove_bullets.append(bullet)
        else:
            bullet.update()
            bullet.draw(screen)
    # remove destroyed bullets from the main list
    for bullet in remove_bullets:
        bullets.remove(bullet)
    
    # update
    enemy.update()
    enemy.draw(screen)

    player.update()
    player.draw(screen)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # usually you would just pass a list of entities that are not like
            # this but rather referenced by name so you would use that
            # instead of passing a list like this. In that case it would make more
            # sense to have an excluded entity as in this case you could just not include
            # in the list at all. Also going over a list to remove a single element
            # would likely be more wasteful
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                # if a pressed create a bullet traveling from enemy to player
                bullet = Bullet(enemy.rect.center, -1, [player, enemy], enemy)
                bullets.append(bullet)
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                # if d pressed create a bullet traveling from player to enemy
                bullet = Bullet(player.rect.center, 1, [player, enemy], player)
                bullets.append(bullet)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Also I feel like you don't need 5 bullet classes (and definitely not 5 for enemies and players), if the bullets behave similarly you should be able to simply change some arguments for the bullet instead of making 5 classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
bullets = []
to shoot, append this V to list
[[positionX, positionY], [directionX, directionY], Rect for the bullet]

collisions:
for bullet in bullets:
  <update stuff here>
  if bullet[2].colliderect(playerrect): # (rect)
    bullets.remove(bullet)
    pass
```